# Add a grid inside bounding boxes in an image

Tags: python, tensorflow, opencv

I have an image with bounding boxes surrounding cones, and I need to put a grid inside each box. How do I extract the bounding box from the image?

[image: Example of the expected result]

I can design the grid already inside the entire image.

Comment: Threshold on bounding box colors the detect blobs.

Comment: Can you write a better response? I didn't understand what you wrote

Comment: what made those pictures? why don't you simply use the coordinates of those boxes, which surely must already exist, because something drew those boxes?

Answer (score 0):

First find the color of the bounding boxes.
I used the chrome add-on [ColorPick eyedropper](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/colorpick-eyedropper/ohcpnigalekghcmgcdcenkpelffpdolg) to extract the RGB colors.

[image: eyedropper result]

```
RGB = (54, 243, 244)
```

Than extract the Blue channel which has the most prominent values.

```
image_b = image_rgb[:,:,-1]
```

If the image is in the opencv BGR channel order do

```
image_b = image_rgb[:,:,0]
```

Threshold the blue channel to get a binary image with just the bounding boxes.

```
cv2.threshold(image_b, 200, 255, cv2.THRESH_BINARY)
```

Then find contours of boxes:

```
cnts = cv2.findContours(gray_image, cv2.RETR_LIST , cv2.CHAIN_APPROX_NONE)
```

The next step would be to find the bounding box of the contours.

```
for cnt in cnts:
    x, y, w, h= cv2.boundingRect(cnt[0])
```